# Why are the "Top Questions" list and "All Questions" list at disjoint locations in the nav scheme?

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-experience

**TLDR:**

Why doesn't the UX for the two different top level question filters look like this:
[image: Possible revised scheme]

**FULL VERSION:**

Stack Overflow provides two separate high level filter options for question lists: "Top Questions", and "All Questions."  These options are available under two different points within the site's navigation scheme:

1. [Home Page (aka Top Questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/)

- available filter buttons here are Interesting, Bountied, Hot, Week and Month

2. [Questions (aka All Questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) menu option under PUBLIC top level menu option

- filter buttons here are Newest and Active
- additional mutually exclusive filter options available under "More"
- various additional filter options are avaiable under "Filter"

Having two separate navigation paths for these alternate schemes - each at different levels of the navigation hierarchy - instead of folding them both under the same entry point seems like suboptimal UX design with a few specific shortcomings that come to mind:

a. I imagine all users would like to know that these two separate top level filter schemes exist.  Yet, having to figure out that one type of question filter is available on the homepage and the other type is one level down from a top level nav menu option does not seem intuitive for new users at the site.  I imagine some amount of time and effort is spent before a new user will grok that these two different options exist and where to find each.

b. Even for experienced users, this scheme seems like an oddball/inconsistent aspect of an otherwise intuitive UX.  (It is well established that consistency is a core tenant of design for enabling an optimal user experience, so I will leave it as self evident that oddball/inconsistent facets in a UI are suboptimal.)

As an alternative, why not fold both question list filters under a single entry point (i.e. the "Questions" menu option under PUBLIC) and then have an "All Questions" button and "Top Questions" button to toggle between the two schemes?  It strikes me that this approach affords all of the same functionality in a more intuitive, self-documenting UX.  (This change would make the homepage and Questions menu option redundant, and I acknowledge some rethinking would be required to address this, but that strikes me as an opportunity rather than a problem.)

(As an addendum, I do not see any content in the SO Help Section establishing that the two separate filter schemes currently exist.  If the above proposed change is not sensible, perhaps updating the Help Section to include a brief account alerting users that these two schemes are available and explaining where they exist within the site navigation would be a useful add for newcomers.)